# Long error while installing @wdio/cucumber-framework in Windows

Tags: npm-install, webdriver-io, node-gyp

I'm trying to install @wdio/cucumber-framework but I get quite a long error. I have tried to install windows-build-tools. I have also installed Visual C++ build tools for Visual Studio 2019.

Here is my output:

```
~\source\repos\myapp> npm install @wdio/cucumber-framework
npm WARN deprecated cucumber@6.0.5: The npm package has moved to @cucumber/cucumber
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\xxxx\source\repos\myapp\node_modules\fibers
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node build.js || nodejs build.js
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@7.1.2
npm ERR! gyp info using node@14.15.4 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.9.1 found at "C:\xxxx\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe"
npm ERR! gyp info find VS using VS2019 (16.8.30907.101) found at:
npm ERR! gyp info find VS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional"
npm ERR! gyp info find VS run with --verbose for detailed information
npm ERR! gyp info spawn C:\xxxx\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\xxxx\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\gyp\\gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'msvs',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\xxxx\\source\\repos\\myapp\\node_modules\\fibers\\build\\config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\xxxx\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\xxxx\\AppData\\Local\\node-gyp\\Cache\\14.15.4\\include\\node\\common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=C:\\xxxx\\AppData\\Local\\node-gyp\\Cache\\14.15.4',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=C:\\xxxx\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=C:\\\\Users\\\\xxx\\\\AppData\\\\Local\\\\node-gyp\\\\Cache\\\\14.15.4\\\\<(target_arch)\\\\node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=C:\\xxxx\\source\\repos\\myapp\\node_modules\\fibers',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\xxxx\\source\\repos\\myapp\\node_modules\\fibers\\build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! gyp info spawn C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build/binding.sln',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/clp:Verbosity=minimal',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/nologo',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/p:Configuration=Release;Platform=x64'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! gyp ERR! build error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe` failed with exit code: 3221225477
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\xxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:194:23)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:277:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19041
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\xxxx\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--release"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\xxxx\source\repos\myapp\node_modules\fibers
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v14.15.4
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v7.1.2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! node-gyp exited with code: 1
npm ERR! Please make sure you are using a supported platform and node version. If you
npm ERR! would like to compile fibers on this machine please make sure you have setup your
npm ERR! build environment--
npm ERR! Windows + OS X instructions here: https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp
npm ERR! Ubuntu users please run: `sudo apt-get install g++ build-essential`
npm ERR! Alpine users please run: `sudo apk add python make g++`
npm ERR! 'nodejs' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
npm ERR! operable program or batch file.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\xxxx\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-02-05T12_32_34_788Z-debug.log
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there something with Visual Studio? Is the Node version 14.15.4 not supported? Is there something with node-gyp?

What should I do to make this pass?

Answer (score 0):

Install node-gyp globally and follow steps for windows documented

https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-gyp